# Type variable vs instanceof for identification

Tags: java, instanceof

I have two classes that are subclasses of an abstract class `A`:

```
class X extends A {}
class Y extends A {}
```

I would like to identify the subclass of an `A` object passed to a function. I can see two alternatives:

```
void myfunction(A myobj) {
    if(myobj instanceof X)
        doXStuff((X) myobj);
    if(myobj instanceof Y)
        doYStuff((Y) myobj);
}
```

or add an `enum` to `A` with the different types:

```
abstract class A {
    enum Type { X, Y };
    Type type;
    ...
}

class X extends A {
    type = Type.X;
    ...
}
class Y extends A {
    type = Type.Y;
    ...
}

void myfunction(A myobj) {
    if(myobj.type == Type.X)
        doXStuff((X) myobj);
    if(myobj.type == Type.Y)
        doYStuff((Y) myobj);
}
```

Which is better? I am leaning towards the second, because `instanceof` doesn't feel right for a production application. Is there another, best way? If the second is better, is there a better place to put the `enum`?

Comment: neither of them is better. For 90% of cases, if you need to get an interface and determine the concrete class before you can do specialized logic, you are designing wrong.

Comment: There are certainly arguments for and against using `instanceof`.  But for goodness sake, if you need something that works like `instanceof`, do NOT re-invent the wheel.  If you can't use polymorphism in the style of Jeroen's answer, then your first solution is much, much better than your second (sorry Adrian).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are bad.

Define the method in `A`, override the method in `X` and `Y` and call that method on the object passed in. You're throwing away polymorphism, a cornerstone of object oriented programming.

```
abstract class A {
    void doStuff();
}

class Y extends A {
    @Override
    void doStuff() {
        // Y specific implementation
    }
}

class X extends A {
    @Override
    void doStuff() {
        // X specific implementation
    }
}
```

Call it using

```
void myfunction(A myobj) {
    myobj.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: @pbabcdefp: `A` is already a class as indicated by the OP so I'm not going to change it considering there might be more to it. I can't tell whether it is supposed to be a class or an interface based on an abstract example. I'll give you *prograpping* though.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I hadn't even considered going about it in your way.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer would be: "both are bad".

It might be a nice solution in terms of implementation, but I think it is not a nice solution in terms of design.

Particularly, it is a violation of the Single Responsibilty Principle. You put alien code into class `X` and `Y`, but this code belongs to the `Client`, which used `X` and `Y`.

Another point is that you need in to use casting in both cases.

```
do_stuff(Object generic_data){((cast_so_special_class)generic_data).do_something_spcial_class_specific();}
```